# cat my.txt | my.exe in windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows

> cat my.txt | my.exe in windows

cat my.txt | my.exe в данном случае my.exe должен получать данные из my.txt, как это написать на windows?

Comment: Не думаю в Win есть конвееры. Пишите открытие файла в my.exe

Comment: `type my.txt | my.exe` - то же самое, только type вместо cat.

Comment: Но вообще, это делается проще: `my.exe < my.txt`

Comment: @Hellseher Интересное у вас представление о Windows. Конвееры вполне себе были даже еще в DOS!

Answer (score 4):

Вот так вот `my.exe < my.txt`